# Selenium Python - Can't click on element

Tags: python, selenium, click, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to selenium click on the "next" button at the bottom of the page (just as shown by cursor in image)
[image]

Here's the link to full web: http://hr.jsbchina.cn/zp/trs/hotPostList.do

I've tried three methods:

1) The conventional click

```
nextbutton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[5]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
nextbutton.click()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

2) The "element_to_be_clickable"

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/form/table[5]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a'))).click() 
time.sleep(10)
```

3) I've also tried adding the page number to the page "text field" and clicking on "Go". And I've tried resizing window size as follows:

```
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Are there any other methods to click on "next"? Because the rest can't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below locators should help you.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('next')
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('next')
```